# Can I access the calling object on an active record association in a has-and-belongs-to-many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, rails-activerecord

If we have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship like this:

```
class Assembly < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parts
end

class Part < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assemblies
end
```

And we use an association to find parts belonging to an `Assembly` with `id` of `1` like this:

```
Assembly.find(1).parts
```

Then is there a way to reference the object that called associated objects - in this case, a way to reference the specific `Assembly` from the `Part` ? Something like this:

```
Assembly.find(1).parts.each do |part|

  the_calling_assembly = part.assembly_that_referenced_me()

end
```

And, of there is not an builtin way to do this, any suggestions on how to create this behavior?

Comment: If you just assigned `Assemby.find(1)` to a variable then your problem is solved, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just an idea

If you go to http://api.rubyonrails.org/ and select `Active Record/Associations` you will see that there are 2 classes

1) [Collection Proxies](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html)

2) [Class Methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations.html)

but also you can see al the classes and modules for the `Association`, but I believe you should patch the [`Collection Proxies` class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html)

so you create the class in `lib/core_ext/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb` and you create an initializer to `required` at your server startup.

if this is what you want to achieve

```
Assembly.find(1).parts.each do |part|

  the_calling_assembly = part.assembly_that_referenced_me()

end
```

you can just create a `method` that does it. It is a good idea to check the `CollectionProxy` class on github

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    class CollectionProxy < Relation
       def parent_instance
           Assembly.find(self.assembly_id)
       end
    end
  end
end
```

so this is not a complete answer and probably I did not realize the complexity of your functionalities, but I suggest you to decrease the complexity.

Also understand what is the `class` from `assembly_part`, because that is the one you need to patch. (`assembly_part.class`)

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about Collection Proxies. After a little searching found [Extending has_many association proxy](http://www.chrisrolle.com/en/blog/extending-has_many-association-proxy) which seems to be what I was trying to get to

Comment: @cwq you are using a block, to iterate with that method. 
Basically you are calling the method `has_many` with `Assembly.first.parts` , but by using a block you pass a piece of code in your call `Assembly.first.parts {|parent| puts parent }` .. The block will do the following `def parts; yield parts.parent; end`, yield will `iterate` between the `method` and the `block`. It will return `parts.parent` to `{|parent| // your code}` then the `block` will `print parent`. I am also new to blocks but they are the most awesome feature of rails and your questions is really awesome

Comment: @cwq the sourcecode from rails include more info on how you can use that class `association proxy` to pass blocks https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bdf412b4eb32f9ef46b3958e71d4e8075fee1e6d/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L64
by searching `block` inside that code you can find out more about it. I am not 100% sure about what I am posting

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is by using a join model for the join table that is used to implement the many-to-many relation.

So, by now there should be a table, `assemblies_parts`

You should write a model:

```
#assemblies_part.rb

class AssemblyPart < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :assembly
    belongs_to :part
end
```

And you should change your other models too

```
class Assembly < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :assembly_parts
    has_many :parts, through: :assembly_parts
end

class Part < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :assembly_parts
    has_many :assemblies, through: :assembly_parts
end
```

So, you could now do;

```
Assembly.find(1).assembly_parts.each do |assembly_part|
     assembly = assembly_part.assembly
     part = assembly_part.part
end
```

If you would like to persist the assembly to the part, throughout the process, you could do the following (caution: this does not persist to the DB)

```
class Part < ApplicationRecord
    #...

    attr_accessor :assembly

end
```

And do this next:

```
Assembly.find(1).assembly_parts.each do |assembly_part|
     part = assembly_part.part
     part.assembly = assembly_part.assembly #only valid through the current process
end
```

By using the `attr_accessor` you can also do this without the join model n implementation.

No new migrations are required for the above solution. Minor typos or syntax errors might exist because I'm doing this on a phone screen.
I hope it helps, anyhow.